# Как исправить баг с некорректным отображением панели задач windows 11?

Tags: windows

Перешел на тестовую версию windows-11. Заметил, что панель задач справа отображается некорректно и имеет отступ. Можно ли это, как то исправить или нужно ждать релиза основной версии?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ставил начисто или обновлением с 10ки? Если с 10ки то совет попробовать начисто. Если уже начисто то... Поздравляю, походу ты попал в компанию ко мне и остальным у кого 11 работает не очень корректно...

Comment: @Gh0sTG0, с этой панелью вечно проблемы. У меня она просто пропадала вечно, помогло изменить язык системы на английский.